# R : Shut down computer after running script (windows 10) not working

Tags: r, shutdown

Shut down computer after running script (windows 10) not working.
I am running a long R script and would like the computer to automatically shut down when the program  is finished. I tried

```
system("shutdown -f -t 1")
```

at the end of the script but it did not work. I got an error message:

```
running command 'shutdown -f -t 1' had status 1
```

I would be grateful for your help.

As suggested, I tried:shell("shutdown /f", wait=F, intern=T) but this logs me out and does not shut the computer down

Comment: Shouldn't it be slash? Try shell("shutdown /f", wait=F, intern=T). Save your work before u run this in your rgui

Comment: Test if `shutdown -f -t 1` works on cmd.

Comment: Thanks, I tried:shell("shutdown /f", wait=F, intern=T) but this logs me out and does not shut the computer down.